# Compile two versions of document

Tags: errors, environments

I'm trying to create two different versions of a document from the same source code. One of the versions should exclude the confidential parts of the document while the other version should retain it.

My idea is to the *Tagging package* to create the two different versions by simply including or omitting the tag *\usetag{closed}*. When I omit the tag I get the error messages included in the bottom.

I need to use it in an environment or commands since I use this function many times during the document.

**Exapmle**

```
\documentclass{article}

%%%%% Other packeges used in project %%%%%
\usepackage[english]{babel} % danske overskrifter
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Skal passe til editorens indstillinger
\usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % fonte (output)
\usepackage{lmodern} % vektor fonte
\usepackage{graphicx} % indsættelse af billeder
\usepackage{epstopdf} %Tilfj "--enable-write18" i argumentet for LaTex build. Dette vil konvertere .eps figurer til pdf-format
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue}
\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{eso-pic}% http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{enumitem}

%%%%% Packege Which I'm trying to implement %%%%%
\usepackage{tagging}

%%%%% Blind Text %%%%%
\usepackage{blindtext}

%%%%% Code %%%%%
%\usetag{closed}

\newenvironment{myenvironment}
{
    \color{gray}
    \begin{taggedblock}{closed}
}
{ 
    \end{taggedblock}
}


\begin{document}

\section{This is public}
\blindtext

\begin{myenvironment}
\section{This is Confidential}
\blindtext
\end{myenvironment}

\section{This is public again}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

**Error messages**

```
Runaway argument?

! File ended while scanning use of \next.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> main.tex

I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.

 main.tex



Emergency stop.

<*> main.tex

*** (job aborted, no legal \end found)


Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 8935 strings out of 492164
 135695 string characters out of 6125314
 242536 words of memory out of 5000000
 13108 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 18746 words of font info for 18 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 39i,0n,40p,886b,321s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I think that the [comment](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/comment) package does exactly what you want.

Comment: You might also just use \newif\ifSomeUniqueName and set \SomeUniqueNametrue or \SomeUniqueNamefalse.

Answer (score 1):

I think the package you're trying to create, already exists: `multiaudience`.

With this package, you can generate different versions of the same document for different audiences.

In the following examples, I define two "audiences": "public" and "confidential".

```
\SetNewAudience{public}
\SetNewAudience{confidential}
```

And I put into

```
\begin{shownto}{confidential}
...
\end{shownto}
```

what should be confidential.

Then I set the audience I want (you can do it also externally, when you are compiling your document, see the [package documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/multiaudience)).

For example, this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
%%%%% Other packages used in project %%%%%
\usepackage[english]{babel} % danske overskrifter
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Skal passe til editorens indstillinger
\usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % fonte (output)
\usepackage{lmodern} % vektor fonte
\usepackage{graphicx} % indsættelse af billeder
\usepackage{epstopdf} %Tilfj "--enable-write18" i argumentet for LaTex build. Dette vil konvertere .eps figurer til pdf-format
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue}
\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{eso-pic}% http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{multiaudience}
\SetNewAudience{public}
\SetNewAudience{confidential}

%%%%% Blind Text %%%%%
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\DefCurrentAudience{public}

\section{This is public}
\blindtext

\begin{shownto}{confidential}
\section{This is Confidential}
\blindtext
\end{shownto}

\section{This is public again}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

produces this output:

[image]

whereas this code (the only difference is  `\DefCurrentAudience{confidential}`):

```
\documentclass{article}
%%%%% Other packages used in project %%%%%
\usepackage[english]{babel} % danske overskrifter
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Skal passe til editorens indstillinger
\usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % fonte (output)
\usepackage{lmodern} % vektor fonte
\usepackage{graphicx} % indsættelse af billeder
\usepackage{epstopdf} %Tilfj "--enable-write18" i argumentet for LaTex build. Dette vil konvertere .eps figurer til pdf-format
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue}
\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{eso-pic}% http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{multiaudience}
\SetNewAudience{public}
\SetNewAudience{confidential}

%%%%% Blind Text %%%%%
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\DefCurrentAudience{confidential}

\section{This is public}
\blindtext

\begin{shownto}{confidential}
\section{This is Confidential}
\blindtext
\end{shownto}

\section{This is public again}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

produces this output:

[image]